# http.get().pipe() - unable to get the actual response object from server for logging

Tags: angular, rxjs

Use case - make a http get call to the server. Log the actual response from the server. Convert the response object (convert epoch date fields to javascript Date). Then return the converted object.

Code snippet -

```
/** GET users from the server */
  getUsers(): Observable<IUser[]> {
    this.logger.log(`GET on ${this.baseUrl}`);
    return this.http.get<IUser[]>(this.baseUrl).pipe(
      tap(users => this.logger.log(`fetched users - `, users)),
      map(users => {
        return users.map(user => this.convertResponse(user));
      }),
      catchError(handleError.bind({ logger: this.logger }))
    );
  }
```

Currently I am using tap() to log the response. Then convert the response object using map(). But the log message displayed is of the converted object and not the original response from the server.

How do I capture the response object before converting it?

Edit -

```
  private convertResponse(user: IUser): IUser {
    user.createdDate = new Date(user.createdDate);
    user.modifiedDate = new Date(user.modifiedDate);
    return user;
  }
```

Comment: Please post the `convertResponse` method.

Comment: added the `convertResponse` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `convertResponse` method mutates the objects in the array (and then returns the mutated object). You *do* log the "non-transformed" version of your array, but by the time you hit "expend" in the developer tools, the mutation already happened, and you're viewing at what the objects look like *after* your mutation happened.

When expanding an object in Chrome, you can see this warning if you hover the blue "i" tooltip [image: tooltip] next to the expansion.

[image: full image]

Change your `convertResponse` method to return a new object instead.

```
  private convertResponse(user: IUser): IUser {
    return {
      ...user,
      createdDate = new Date(user.createdDate),
      modifiedDate = new Date(user.modifiedDate),
    }
  }
```